# Multiple numbering series within a single document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I have a large multilingual document which has each content page twice, one in english and one with the same content in another language. The content has many headings with multilevel numbering. Clearly, if the english page contains this content:

```
3. Heading
3.1. Subheading
text
3.2. Subheading
text
```

then the page after should contain the same numbering structure, and the page after that should continue with chapter 4, as well as the page after that. It seems that this requires to have a second numbering series (otherwise it would be necessary to manually decrease the numbering value at the beginning of each translated page, which doesn't seem like a good solution to me). Is this possible in Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Word supports maintaining separate lists regardless of their position or proximity to other lists in the document.

The easiest way to set them up is to restart numbering on a single list which splits it in two and then copy and paste at least one item from each list to continue them elsewhere in the document, see below for a demonstration of this.

[image]

Hint: To tell what list an item belongs to click its number and the number label of all items that belong to that list are shaded grey.